# Add datetime picker custom field to every product page on WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, datetimepicker, custom-fields, product

I want to add `datetimepicker.js` to every `product page`, so, the customer could be able to choose the date and time of the appointment.

The selected date and time should be visible on product's title, which is displayed on cart etc.

Is there any way or hook that i can add custom fields on product page?

Comment: have you tried something

Comment: @MeerDeen What do you mean? I want to do this with custom code but i did not find any hooks or functions that woocommerce provide so i can do anything. Found many tutorials for custom product fields on back end but noone on frond end..